# RegEx for matching the first word

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the following prop {priority} that outputs ‘high priority’, is there a way I can render it simply as ‘high’? could I use standard js or something like the below?

```
var getPriority = {priority};
var priority = getPriority.replace( regex );
console.log( priority );
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Would just doing `getPriority.replace('priority', '').trim()` work for your needs?

Comment: you can just split on spaces and pull the first out. `var [ priority ] = getPriority.split(' ')`, you don't need regexp here.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to do that with a regular expression, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/8L2Mm1/1) would do so, even if there might be a misspelling in the word "priority":

```
(.+)(\s[priorty]+)
```

[image]

It can simply use capturing groups for capturing your desired word before "priority". If you wish to add any boundaries to it, it would be much easier to do so, especially if your input string would change.

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

```js
const regex = /(.+)(\s[priorty]+)/gmi;
const str = `high priority
low priority
medium priority
under-processing pririty
under-processing priority
400-urget priority
400-urget Priority
400-urget PRIority`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = "high priority";
 var regex = /(.+)(\s[priorty]+)/gmi;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get your required string

```
var str = 'high priority';
console.log(str.substring(0, 4));
// expected output: "high"
```

so in your code

```
var getPriority = {priority};
var priority = getPriority.priority.substring(0, 4);
console.log( priority );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the only first element of string using `.split()`:
Code below will show first word of string:

```
var getPriority = {priority};
console.log( getPriority.priority.split(' ', 1)[0]);
```

Or if priority value always has `priority` word in the end, you can get rid of it just making it as a separator for `.split()`:

```
var getPriority = {priority};
console.log( getPriority.priority.split(' priority')[0] );
```